# React Native build fails on building a new build type other than debug/release

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to prepare a staging release build but by my build is failing. It gives me a huge list of errors. I have modified my build.gradle to add a staging environment. I am not sure why this is happening as my debug and release build works fine.

I used `yarn android --variant=stagingrelease` to generate the build and run on my physical android device. Using `React-Native: 0.61.5`.

**Some of the errors are as follows**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preStagingreleaseBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:stagingreleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_masked-view.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :@react-native-community_masked-view:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability Furry:@react-native-community_masked-view:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability Furry:@react-native-community_masked-view:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability Furry:@react-native-community_masked-view:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability Furry:@react-native-community_masked-view:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-bootsplash.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-bootsplash:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-bootsplash:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-bootsplash:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-bootsplash:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-bootsplash:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-config.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-config:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-config:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-config:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-config:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-config:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-gesture-handler.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-gesture-handler:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-gesture-handler:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-gesture-handler:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-gesture-handler:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-gesture-handler:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-reanimated.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-reanimated:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability com.swmansion.reanimated:react-native-reanimated:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability com.swmansion.reanimated:react-native-reanimated:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability com.swmansion.reanimated:react-native-reanimated:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability com.swmansion.reanimated:react-native-reanimated:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-safe-area-context.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-safe-area-context:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-safe-area-context:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-safe-area-context:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability Furry:react-native-safe-area-context:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability Furry:react-native-safe-area-context:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-screens.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching variant of project :react-native-screens:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability com.swmansion.rnscreens:react-native-screens:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability com.swmansion.rnscreens:react-native-screens:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability com.swmansion.rnscreens:react-native-screens:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability com.swmansion.rnscreens:react-native-screens:unspecified:
              - Incompatible attribute:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'stagingrelease' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Other attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

**Snippets of android/app/build.gradle**

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        debug: ".env",
        release: ".env.production",
        stagingrelease: ".env.staging",
]
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.furry"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        stagingrelease {
            initWith release
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02"

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' ]
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
# Add any project specific keep options here:
-keep class com.furry.BuildConfig { *; }
```

**Dependencies in package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.7",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.8",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.44",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.5",
        "react-native-bootsplash": "^1.2.1",
        "react-native-config": "^0.12.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
        "react-native-sms-retriever": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-svg": "^11.0.1",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
        "realm": "4.0.0-beta.0",
        "recyclerlistview": "2.0.13-alpha.1"
    },
```

Comment: did you installed all the modules which are showing like this **Could not resolve project :react-native-screens.** ?

Comment: @AnujSharma yes, they are all in my package.json. And my debug build works fine.

Comment: clean your gradle **gradlew clean**

Comment: already done but didnt work

Comment: set your **build tools version** As 21.1.1

Comment: My build tools are set as `buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"`

Comment: I got it, check the answer

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Alright!, so I have been trying for many hours to resolve the issues and it turns out that there is a simple answer to it, [`matchingFallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolve_matching_errors).

The issue occurs because I am adding a new build variant `stagingrelease` to my app's `build.gradle` whereas the native libraries that am using doesn't have the same matching variant in their `build.gradle` hence during the build the repective libraries are not found.

```
stagingrelease {
    initWith release
    matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release'] // Addded this
}
```

Comment: worked for me too!! i had created a complete new buildType and stagingRelease referenced that as a fallback which it did not like at ALL

Comment: Why did you add both 'debug' and 'release as a matching fallback for this particular configuration? It feels like for the `stagingrelease` config only the `release` fallback is expected. Did I understood the meaning of this correctly? Also `matchingFallbacks` is reported as deprecated.

Comment: This is a deprecated notation, the new notation is to use `.add`: `matchingFallbacks.addAll("debug", "release")` or add a specific one with `matchingFallbacks.add("release")`

Comment: Hi @Mando, could you share the URL of the doc where it's stated that matchingFallbacks is deprecated?

Comment: I don't have doc ref but Android Studio tells that: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36530#issuecomment-1476469683

Comment: I suppose this notation isn't updated in the docs.

Comment: It also worked for me, but the order matters. It need to be on the top like the code above and after that your other configs

Answer (score 0):

try this commands one by one in your project directory

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
```

wipe data of your virtual device
start virtual device again

run `npx react-native run-android`

this will help you to build debug apk again. It will remove all previous apks.

Comment: I have tried the above procedure. But my issue is not with the debug build. Its with the release and release staging builds.

Comment: `yarn android --variant=releasestaging` for staging build.

Comment: share package.json file image

Comment: shared the dependencies that are installed

Answer (score 0):

Android Support Repository was missing installed, again followed all the steps here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2772#issuecomment-140843907

Some of the packages have been renamed, particularly "Android Support Repository" seems to have been renamed to "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries". Installing it fixed the error for me.

Comment: am not sure but my build.gradle has `maven` keywords present

Comment: do this once and let's check there is something is missing maybe

Comment: Check my build.gradle. Also a small hunch because the issue is of 2015, don't you think this is already solved by the RN team and already available in the packages.

Comment: Don't know much but there is something wrong in your packages, so you have to check your packages carefully

Comment: I too am not sure whats wrong over here. And for the packages, they are all updated to the very recent versions. :(

Comment: try **gradlew clean** and the start and solve error step by steps it will help you

Comment: start building your project from starting

Comment: That's not possible.